Scheduling Curing Tasks in an Aerospace Composite Materials Processing Plant Using OptaPlanner
Background
In the aerospace composite materials processing plant, the "curing" process requires the use of autoclaves, which are a scarce resource for the factory. To improve efficiency, it is necessary to schedule the curing requirements of various parts (referred to as curing tasks) as follows:
Key attributes of curing tasks:

Task ID (uniquely identifies the task)
Expected arrival time of the task
Curing parameters used by the task; tasks with the same curing parameters can be scheduled in the same autoclave simultaneously.
Duration specified in the curing parameters, representing the time the autoclave will be occupied (tasks with the same curing parameters have the same curing duration).
Base area of the tooling; the area required for the task in the autoclave.
Maximum waiting time for curing, aiming to execute within this time.

The factory has multiple autoclave devices, and their key attributes include:

Autoclave ID
Capacity—the area that the autoclave can accommodate corresponding to the base area of the curing task.

Requirements

Assume all autoclaves are initially available.
Group the curing tasks based on curing parameters, expected arrival time, and the current occupation time of the planned autoclaves.
Schedule this batch of tasks into the autoclaves.
Each autoclave can only execute one batch task at a time.
The total base area of tasks in a batch cannot exceed the autoclave's capacity.
Minimize the waiting time for all curing tasks.

Problem
How do I model this?
My difficulty lies in the need to plan curing tasks into batch tasks and allocate those batch tasks to specific equipment all at once. Planning batch tasks is challenging because:
I need to consider which future tasks will arrive and whether they use the same planning parameters.
After grouping the curing tasks with the same curing parameters, I cannot proceed further. I don’t know which group of curing parameters to schedule first, which autoclave to assign them to, and how to further batch tasks with the same curing parameters (considering equipment capacity limits).
I am uncertain whether OptaPlanner supports this scenario.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If there's one job (task) per machine (autoclave) at a time, it's a job shop scheduling problem, take a look at the food-packaging quickstart in timefold-quickstarts (OptaPlanner is EOL and continues as Timefold).
If there's multiple jobs per machine at the same time:

either it allows for auto-collapse (see docs, scroll down)
or it's a 2D surface or 3D volume bin packing problem (time vs autoclave occupancy), which isn't well supported yet.

